# Screen auto rotate (Landscpe flipped) when switching on my lenovo

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, lenovo, display-resolution, xrandr

When I start my laptop that time my screen rotate automatically it shows (landscape flipped) inside setting and if i leave my laptop idle and it goes into sleep mode this problem occurs then also I have tried many things to solve this issue

`xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --rotate left`

I used `xrandr -q` to find my display name

Second issue is when i close my lid my laptop goes off and doesn't switch on i have to cold boot my laptop to switch it on again